# passing class X into generic class does not return expected instance of class X

Tags: flowtype

I am struggling here. I am trying to pass a class into a class to return an instance of that class, when using class methods.

```
class FakeClass {}

const fakeClass = new FakeClass()

class Selector <X> {
  model: x;
  constructor(model: X){
    this.model = model
  }
  getModel = () : X => {
    return this.model
  }
}

const selector : Selector<FakeClass> = new Selector(fakeClass)

const result : FakeClass = selector.getModel()
```

//Error

```
61: const result : FakeClass = selector.getModel()
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ X. This type is incompatible with
 61: const result : FakeClass = selector.getModel()
                    ^^^^^^^^^ FakeClass
```

Any ideas about this? I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you change

```
getModel = () : X => {
```

to a normal method as

```
getModel() : X {
```

it will work.

I don't know if this would be considered a Flow bug or not. It seems as though Flow is unable to handle this usage of the arrow function for some reason. Perhaps someone who knows more could provide more explanation than I can.

Comment: This. Saved. My. Life. If I had 15 more points I would upvote you